# What is this PHP syntax with a caret called and what does it do?

Tags: php, syntax, operators

I came across this syntax in a codebase and I can't find any more info on it. It looks like the caret operator (XOR operator), but because the statement below was executed when a certain condition was met I don't think that is it.

```
$this->m_flags ^= $flag;
```

Because I don't know what it's called I also can't search for it properly..

Update:
Because of Cletus' answer:
Are the following lines then functionally equal?

```
$a = $a ^ $b; 
$a ^= $b; // the shorthand for the line above
```

Comment: Yes, they are functionally equal.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's [bitwise XOR equals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php). It basically toggles a flag because I'm getting `$flag` is a power-of-2. To give you an example:

```
$a = 5; // binary 0101
$b = 4; // binary 0100
$a ^= $b; // now 1, binary 0001
```

So the third bit has been flipped. Again:

```
$a ^= $b; // now 5, binary 0101
```

Comment: $b = 4; // binary must be 0100

Answer (score 3):

Bitwise XOR and assign operator
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: I only see ^= used in the comments. Is there any official documentation for this?

Comment: It is the same thing as saying `$this->m_flags = $this->m_flags ^ $flags`

Comment: It's shorthand for `$this->m_flags = $this->m_flags ^ $flag;` the same way as `$i += 1` is short for `$i = $i + 1` or `$j *= 2` is short for `$j = $j * 2`. It's a standard syntax in C-type languages.

Comment: "In addition to the basic assignment operator, there are "combined operators" for all of the binary arithmetic, array union and string operators that allow you to use a value in an expression and then set its value to the result of that expression." http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

Comment: Imho the docs could be more clear and give more exhaustive examples. But thanks for explaining!

Comment: It definitely can be tricky sometimes. Especially with regards to operators that you don't know what the official name is.