# Why does the PHP Exponent Operator (^) give back a wrong result?

Tags: php

I made a simple weight tracking app in PHP and am comparing it with what I used to have in Google Sheets, and I'm noticing a difference in a number coming back from "floor".

In Google Sheets:

```
=FLOOR(84.614285714286 / ((179 / 100) ^ 2))
```

results in: "26"

in PHP 8:

```
floor($currentWeight / (($user['height'] / 100)^2));
```

Results in "28". When I have PHP spit out the value of these variables they are:

```
$currentWeight = 84.614285714286
$user['height'] = 179
($currentWeight / (($user['height'] / 100)^2)) = 28.204761904762
```

What could be the reason for this? Which is right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [pow](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php) method provided by PHP to calculate powers.

Use `pow((179 / 100), 2)` instead of `(179 / 100) ^ 2` in the PHP part.

So, the updated last line should be:

```
$result = floor($currentWeight / (pow($user['height'] / 100), 2));
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/3VUP1

```
Output: 26
```

Comment: Cool, that brings PHP in line with Sheets (which I suppose "fixes" it) but why is PHP letting me get away with "^" and why does it cause a different calculation to be done?

Comment: also see: [^ is a bitwise XOR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029019/what-is-this-php-syntax-with-a-caret-called-and-what-does-it-do)

Comment: Relevant link https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: The short version would be a `**` as the `^` you are used to. @Jobbo

Comment: @Uwe, thanks for adding your valuable input ✨